# ASP.NET CodeBehind C#: How to get cell values of HTML Table from codebehind?

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, code-behind

For example this is the table:

```
<table id="users">
<thead>
  <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Password</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="Name1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Email1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Password1"/></td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="Name2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Email2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="Password2"/></td>
  <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

then I want the codebehind to get the values from the table.. please help.

Comment: i tried foreach(Contron ctrl in users.Control).. but its not working

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `<asp:TextBox>` tag instead of the `<input>` tags. This enables you to get the values from the text boxes in codebehind.
See the [System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) on MSDN.

**UPDATE:**
If you can't change the `<input>` tags to `<asp:TextBox>`, you could access the form values posted through `Request.Form` like this:

```
Request.Form[valueName]
```

Where value name is the name of the value posted.

Comment: So input text is not possible? Actually Im adding row dynamically using javascript and i cant put there asp tags.. quite similar to this http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: If you want to access the values from codebehind you can't use `<input>`. The answer from @Ravindra provides another possibility, but still you can't add a row dynamically from javascript.

Comment: $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
"<td><input type='text'class='customerIDCell'/></td>" +
"<td><input type='text'class='customerIDCell'/></td>" +
"<td><input type='text'class='customerIDCell'/></td>" +
"</tr>"); This is how i create row and its working but i cant change that input to aspTextbox I keep using input

Comment: You could use `Request.Form` to access the values posted through the form. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

Create table to run at server like this

`<table id="users" runat="server">`

and you will be able to access it using HtmlTable class. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable%28v=vs.80%29.aspx